# Picking UVs from Pixel Coordinates Doesn't get all UVs (Painting App)

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, 3d

I am building a painting app where one paints on 3D meshes. To do this, I render the UV coordinates to the screen and pick those to know where I have to paint on the mesh's texture.

[image]

Here you can see the mesh on the top left, its UVs on the top right. I successfully paint on the bottom left. The problem is that not all of the UVs are being rendered to the screen. When the camera zooms in, there are holes in the paint.

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: Render small quads between four adjacent positions that you retrieved from the rendered UV map.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean that I should draw a square for every 4 points to fill in the gaps? What if the 4 points that are adjacent on the screen are on different triangles and not adjacent in texture coordinates? Then it becomes unclear how to fill in the gaps.

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. As you noticed, this simple approach has some drawbacks. Take a look at [this paper](http://www.inf.usi.ch/hormann/papers/Scharfig.2010.HA3.pdf) and its Related Work section to see some more involved approaches.

Comment: Thank you! I rendered the small quads using the method provided in the paper to account for UV seams. The only extra step was that I had to generate a secondary set of UVs to minimize the amount of UV shells.